# pdf_tex not found

Tags: bibliographies, babel, import, shorthands

I am writing my PhD in Polish. I use `pdf_tex` files for inserting images.

This is the file which is working fine

```
\documentclass[oneside, 12pt]{book}
\usepackage[top=2.5cm, bottom=2.5cm, left=2.5cm, right=2.5cm]{geometry}
\linespread{1.3} %Interlinia 1.5

\usepackage{polski}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{import} 

\begin{document}
Citation of \cite{achtziger1997topology}.

\begin{figure}
  \centering
  \import{"Rysunki/Chapter_2/"}{Przyklad_funkcja.pdf_tex}
  \caption{funkcja}
\end{figure}

\bibliographystyle{abbrv}
\bibliography{Uncertain}

\end{document}
```

But it's nearly fine. Images are imported without errors, chapters are in Polish, but I have English words in the bibliography. I would like change "Ed." to "Red.", etc. One solution I found is the use of `biblatex` (and Biber) with some other packages. So I changed my file to

```
\documentclass[oneside, 12pt]{book}
\usepackage[top=2.5cm, bottom=2.5cm, left=2.5cm, right=2.5cm]{geometry}
\linespread{1.3} %Interlinia 1.5

\usepackage{polski}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\DeclareQuoteAlias{croatian}{polish}
\usepackage[british, polish]{babel}

\usepackage[backend=biber,%
sorting=nyt,%
style=numeric,%
citestyle=numeric,%
giveninits=true,
doi=false, isbn=false, url=false]{biblatex}

\DefineBibliographyStrings{polish}{%
    byeditor = {red\adddot\addcolon},%
}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{import}

\addbibresource{Uncertain.bib}

\begin{document}
Citation of \cite{achtziger1997topology}.

\begin{figure}
    \centering
    \import{"Rysunki/Chapter_2/"}{Przyklad_funkcja.pdf_tex}
    \caption{funkcja}
\end{figure}

\printbibliography[heading=bibintoc]

\end{document}
```

Now bibliography is correct, but when importing pdf_tex image I get an error

```
! LaTeX Error: File `Przyklad_funkcja.pdf_tex' not found.
```

Do you have an idea what goes wrong? Is pdf_tex not working with biber?
Maybe there is another solution for the Polish bibliography?

**Edit:** I use TeXMaker.

Comment: We can't test your code, for we don't have the additional files involved. But my guess here is that babel is the culprit. It does make `"` and active character. Try `\usepackage[british, polish, shorthands=off]{babel}` to see if that is the case.

Comment: I'm not even sure if you need the `"` in `\import{"Rysunki/Chapter_2/"}{Przyklad_funkcja.pdf_tex}`. Does `\import{Rysunki/Chapter_2/}{Przyklad_funkcja.pdf_tex}` not work? Anyway, you may want to try and reduce your MWE and remove `biblatex` and all other packages that don't make a difference.

Comment: Wow. Thank you @gusbrs, @moewe. Both solutions works separately: adding `shorthands=off` or removing the `"`.

Comment: BTW: If the Polish language packages had a similar evolution as German and French, you should probably drop `\usepackage{polski}` when you load `babel`. You should also make sure to load packages only once (`graphicx`). `style=numeric, citestyle=numeric,` is equivalent to `style=numeric,`

Comment: @janekpel, I think you are better off with moewe's suggestion. Disabling `babel`'s shorthands would not be ideal, imo. But removing the quotes will probably work there if you have no spaces in your path (a guess, I'm not acquainted with `import`). If that's a problem, you could consider using `\input`, `\includegraphic` or `\include`, as the case may be, for they will probably have a better standing in this regard than `\import`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems the introduction of `babel` is the culprit to the issue. Indeed, `babel` makes `"` an active character for the Polish language (a sort of single character command), and this affects your call to `\import{"Rysunki/Chapter_2/"}{Przyklad_funkcja.pdf_tex}`.

As your tests indicate, this is the case, given either the introduction of `shorthands=off` to `babel`'s options or the removal or the quotation marks in `\import` fix the problem. As mentioned in the comments, you should prefer removing the quotation marks from your `\import` calls, if it is possible. That would be better than disabling `babel`'s shorthands.

If this introduces new problems, eg. if your paths given in `\import` have spaces,  you could consider using `\input`, `\includegraphic` or `\include`, as the case may be, for they will probably have a better standing in this regard than `\import`.

Finally, if the above fails or is not possible or desired, you could use `babel`'s `\shorthandoff` and `\shorthandon` to locally disable the active character where needed.